# Why isn't sudo apt remove code working to uninstall VS Code?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, uninstallation, apt

VS Code is installed on my Ubuntu machine, but when I try to remove it by using `sudo apt remove code`, it says:

> Package 'code' is not installed, so not removed.

I opened settings, and VS Code is showing up in installed applications, it is also running when I write `code` in the terminal and press enter.

Unfortunately, the Ubuntu Software application is not working, so I have to remove it from the terminal.

What is happening, and how I can remove VS Code?

Comment: where is it installed? what do you see when you run `whereis code`? If you see `/snap/bin/code` you installed it as a snap, and you can uninstall it with `snap remove code`

Answer (score 0):

As found in the comments by running `whereis code`, which gave `/snap/bin/code`, you had installed VS Code as a Snap package. You can remove it via `snap remove code`.